# Running browser process concurrently using schedule and multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, schedule

Even reading the **init** file of the schedule library I didn't find a solution, can someone help me?

Or any other solution that might be better than this one?

I'm trying to run 50 playwright profiles.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #bloco1
    n1 = Process(target=Zipe, args=("01", "01", 5))
    n2 = Process(target=Zipe, args=("01", "05", 10))

    #bloco2
    n3 = Process(target=Zipe, args=("01", "11", 15))
    n4 = Process(target=Zipe, args=("01", "16", 20))

    #bloco3
    n5 = Process(target=Zipe, args=("01", "21", 25))
    n6 = Process(target=Zipe, args=("01", "26", 30))

    #bloco4
    n7 = Process(target=Zipe, args=("01", "31", 35))
    n8 = Process(target=Zipe, args=("01", "36", 40))

    #bloco5
    n9 = Process(target=Zipe, args=("01", "41", 45))
    n10 = Process(target=Zipe, args=("01", "46", 50))

    schedule.every().day.at("06:00").do(n1.start())
    schedule.every().day.at("06:00").do(n2.start())
    schedule.every().day.at("06:00").do(n3.start())
    schedule.every().day.at("06:00").do(n4.start())
    schedule.every().day.at("06:00").do(n5.start())
    schedule.every().day.at("06:00").do(n6.start())
    schedule.every().day.at("06:00").do(n7.start())
    schedule.every().day.at("06:00").do(n8.start())
    schedule.every().day.at("06:00").do(n9.start())
    schedule.every().day.at("06:00").do(n10.start())

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do. Are you trying to run each on a different process?

Comment: It's the same function, this function will run 10 browsers at the same time, with different parameters...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what does `Zipe` do, but here is what I thought will look like the best solution:

```
import schedule
import time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

zipe_args = [
    ("01", "01", 5),
    ("01", "05", 10),
    ("01", "11", 15),
    ("01", "16", 20),
    ("01", "21", 25),
    ("01", "26", 30),
    ("01", "31", 35),
    ("01", "36", 40),
    ("01", "41", 45),
    ("01", "46", 50),
]

def Zipe(*args):
    print(args)

def run_zipe():
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(Zipe, *zip(*zipe_args))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    schedule.every().day.at("06:00").do(run_zipe)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(5)
```

I use `concurrent.futures` with a `ProcessPoolExecutor` in order to run all concurrently. You can use the `max_processes` of the executor to change the number of processes running concurrently.

Comment: this looks a little complex, I'll look into it, thanks for the light

Comment: @wikid I can further explain it, but in this case I highly suggest for you to play with it a little, yes. If you still have doubts, don't hesitate to ask :-)